# Trying to boot linux from live usb for the first time, stuck on GRUB command line

Tags: boot, grub2, opensuse

I'm trying to install openSUSE Tumbleweed to replace Windows 11 on my machine. I've created a live USB stick containing openSUSE Tumbleweed, and set it as the first and only boot option in the UEFI.

Booting from the USB brings up GRUB command line:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

>grub
```

Entering `ls` command outputs:

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,mdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

And entering the `ls` command to show the root partitions for every device name and index, i.e. `ls (hd0,1)/` , outputs:

```
error: ../ ../grub-core/kern/fs.c:121:unkown filesystem
```

except for `(hd1,gpt1)`, where entering the command `ls (hd1,1)/` outputs:

```
efi/ System Volume Information/
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to successfully boot into openSUSE TW, any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me with the current version of the liveTumbleweed iso file **cloned** to a USB drive -- 0. Which iso file (file-name) did you download? 1. Please check with `sha256sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly; 2. Which tool/method did you use to create the USB boot drive? 3. Please tell us the brand name and model of the computer and graphics chip.

Comment: @sudodus 

0. The file name is `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-DVD-x86_64-Snapshot20220614-Media.iso`

1. Following this guide to check the iso on windows: [link](https://www.techsolveprac.com/check-linux-mint-iso/), generates `07d49af21f91846f7e2d2c0cd45697aff271e8ca4934144ce2faa4bd67000beb`

2. I used ISO2USB to create the USB boot drive.

3. The brand is DELL, the model is Latitude 3520 running Intel Xe graphics

Comment: Was the Windows system shutdown with "Fast Boot" option enabled? That will leave the Windows partition unreadable by Linux.

Comment: @waltinator I've just checked and  "Fast Boost"/Fast Startup was enabled by default. I've disabled it and rebooted the system to try booting from the USB again and I'm still encountering the same issue.

Comment: I tried the [persistent] live `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-XFCE-Live-x86_64-Snapshot20220616-Media.iso` in a Dell Precision m4800, but did also a quick check in a Dell Latitude 3520 (the same as yours). I secure boot Ubuntu in the 3520, and the USB drive is **not** seen. With 'Secure boot' still on (shown on the BIOS boot menu page), I switched to 'Audit mode'. Then the USB drive was seen, and Tumbleweed could be booted all the way to the graphical desktop environment. So I suggest that you turn off secure boot or switch to audit mode like I did, and try again. Good luck :-)

Comment: Now I can find only the `openSUSE-Tumbleweed-DVD-x86_64-Snapshot20220616-Media.iso` and its sha256sum-file. It seems you have to download both files during the same day, otherwise it will be too late to find the matching sha256sum file, so let us hope that your download was good.

Comment: @sudodus I've tried switching to audit mode and I'm still encountering the same issue.

Comment: @guest, There are a couple of things that I would suggest doing now: 1. Since we find no checksum for your current iso file, please download a current one + plus its corresponding sha256sum. It might be 'good enough' with a 'live' drive, which is smaller (~1GB, while the 'media' file is >4GB), but both should work for you; 2. Several 'ISO2USB' tools are described at the internet, and I don't know if the tool you used is good. I suggest that you use a tool that is ***cloning*** from the iso file to the USB drive.

Comment: In Windows Rufus clones if and only if you select 'dd-mode'. I am sure Win32DiskImager is a cloning tool, and I think Balena Etcher is a cloning tool. Please tell me if you are working in some Linux system, and which system, and I can suggest which tool to use; 3. Next step would be to completely turn off 'Secure Boot' via the boot menus; 4. Next step is to try to boot in 'recovery mode' (maybe similar wording) and/or use the boot option `nomodeset`.

Comment: @sudodus 1. I've downloaded a current one + its corresponding sha256sum and can confirm that the hashes match: `69835753b082e3248dd56ccaf0ed2bb35dd3be525386225c6822db9b78fc1246`. 2. I am on Windows 11 created the boot drive, this time using Windows Rufus (version 3.18.1877). "Partition scheme" was set to GPT, "File system" was set to NTFS, and "dd-mode" was selected. 3. I have turned off "Secure Boot" via the UEFI. 4. I skipped this step. The result; REJOICE! I was able to successfully boot into openSUSE TW installation screen. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @guest, I'm glad I could help you make the USB drive boot. Congratulations :-)

Answer (score 2):

@sudodus comment solved my problem.

> @guest, There are a couple of things that I would suggest doing now: 1. Since we find no checksum for your current iso file, please download a current one + plus its corresponding sha256sum. It might be 'good enough' with a 'live' drive, which is smaller (~1GB, while the 'media' file is >4GB), but both should work for you; 2. Several 'ISO2USB' tools are described at the internet, and I don't know if the tool you used is good. I suggest that you use a tool that is cloning from the iso file to the USB drive. –
> sudodus

> In Windows Rufus clones if and only if you select 'dd-mode'. I am sure Win32DiskImager is a cloning tool, and I think Balena Etcher is a cloning tool. Please tell me if you are working in some Linux system, and which system, and I can suggest which tool to use; 3. Next step would be to completely turn off 'Secure Boot' via the boot menus; 4. Next step is to try to boot in 'recovery mode' (maybe similar wording) and/or use the boot option nomodeset. – sudodus

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that has to do with the fact that, in their great wisdom, openSUSE decided that they *"knew better"* and [chose to use `/boot/grub2/` as their GRUB prefix instead of the de-facto `/boot/grub/`](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/a9a97b6f102a71a9d713821eb889e5e1bb30f870/src/iso.c#L1114-L1136) (and for the record, they didn't do that because there was a conflicting `/boot/grub/` directory on their image or anything, but apparently *"just because"*...)

This creates an issue when booting in BIOS mode with the current version of Rufus, when the USB drive is written in ISO mode, because, since we need to install a GRUB 2.0 bootloader (unlike UEFI, we can't just pick one present on the ISO), and the GRUB prefix is hardcoded in that bootloader, distros that use a nonstandard prefix create breakage.

We'll add a workaround for that in Rufus 3.19, but in the meantime, and as @sudodus suggested, you should use DD mode when writing your openSUSE media in Rufus, if you are planning to use that media in BIOS/Legacy mode.